# Assigning regex search to variable: Uninitialized variable error

Tags: regex, perl, variables, fasta

I am opening files in a directory that contain two lines of sequences in each file. The top sequence is longer than the bottom, but includes the bottom sequence. I would like to extend the bottom sequence by the two flanking letters in each direction once it is found in the top sequence. I am trying this by a doing a regex match, but am getting a uninitialized error for the $newsequence variable. 
Here is what a typical file looks like:

```
    >CCCCNNNNNCCCC
    NNNNN
```

I would like to print to one file all the sequences in the following format:

```
    >CCCCNNNNNCCCC
    CCNNNNNCC
```

Here is my code so far:

```
    use strict; 
    use warnings; 

    my ($directory) = @ARGV 
    my @array = glob "$directory/*"; 
    my $header; 
    my $sequence; 
    my $newsequence; 

    open(OUT, ">", "/path/to/out.txt") or die $!; 
    foreach my $file (@array){ 
        open (my $fh, $file) or die $!; 
        while (my $line = <$fh>){ 
            chomp $line; 
            if ($line =~ /^>/) { 
                $header = $line; 
            } elsif ($line =~ /^[CN]/) { 
                $sequence = $line; 
            } 
            my ($newsequence) = $header =~ /(([CN]{2})($sequence)([CN]{2}))/; 
        } 
        print OUT $header, "\n", $newsequence, "\n"; 
    }
```

How can I improve my regex assignment to $newsequence to get adequate output? Thanks.

Comment: Which variable is uninitialized?

Comment: What's the exact warning message?

Comment: Barmar- The $newsequence variable is uninitialized. I will improve my question to include that info. zdim- I am simply taking the two letters that flank the bottom sequence on either side, when it is found in the top sequence. I will clarify that also. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
my ($newsequence) = $header =~ /(([CN]{2})($sequence)([CN]{2}))/;
```

The `my` keyword is creating a new variable `$newsequence` local to the `while` loop, not assigning the variable in the main script. So when you try to write `$newsequence` after the loop is done, the variable is still uninitialized.

Either put the `print` statement inside the `while` loop, or remove the `my` keyword in this assignment.

Also, you should put that assignment statement inside the `elseif` block. Otherwise, you'll try to use `$sequence` before you've assigned it. So the whole thing should look like:

```
foreach my $file (@array){ 
    open (my $fh, $file) or die $!; 
    while (my $line = <$fh>){ 
        chomp $line; 
        if ($line =~ /^>/) { 
            $header = $line; 
        } elsif ($line =~ /^[CN]/) { 
            $sequence = $line; 
            ($newsequence) = $header =~ /(([CN]{2})($sequence)([CN]{2}))/; 
            print OUT $header, "\n", $newsequence, "\n"; 
        } 
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your conditions are accurate (each file contains only 2 lines, and the sequence is always found in the header), then you can make your code a lot simpler, including the regex:

```
for my $file (@array) {
  open (my $fh, $file) or die $!;
  chomp ((my $header, my $sequence) = <$fh>);
  $header =~ /(..)$sequence(..)/;
  print OUT "$header\n$1$sequence$2";
}
```